# Setting username and password in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to set the username and password in phpmyadmin for mysql.

I think the default username is root@localhost.

I do not know how to set this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 'root' user would have been setup during the initial install. If you open the `config.default.php` file you will see

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '********';
```

This information can be changed provided you are not using 'cookie' validation. Like this

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Comment: hi, in version 4.8.3 of phpMyAdmin, **config.default.php** greets you with a big ***NO! DO NOT EDIT!***, then it slightly more gently says **DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT** ***config.inc.php*** **INSTEAD !!!**. just saying...

Comment: @Scaramouche Fair enough. For those interested, the `config.inc.php` must be manually created. You can find those instructions [here](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manually-creating-the-file).

Answer (score -1):

Open Cpanel

Go To MySQLDatabases

Find **MySQL Users**

"Add new User"

Remember the username will be in the format domainname_username.

Comment: This assumes he has CPanel :\